# Evaluate $2^{-n}(2^n-2^{1+n})$

Tags: exponentiation

The answer is $-1$, but how does one expand and simplify this expression to find this answer (what are the steps)?

Comment: Distributing that $2^{-n}$ would be a good first step.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT : 
$$A(B+C)=AB+AC$$
and$$2^a\times 2^b=2^{a\color{red}{+}b}.$$

Comment: Would you please be more direct? I understand this exponent law, but not how to apply it to this situation (expression).

Comment: @ArthurAlexKarapetov: Can you try to use my hints?

Answer (score 2):

$$2^{-n}(2^n-2^{n+1})=2^{n-n}-2^{n+1-n}=1-2=-1$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought you had to use multiplication of exponents rather than addition, very foolish of me. Thanks again.